# Extending custom interface of array within other interface

Tags: typescript, interface

I keep getting an error during compilation:
error TS2339 Property 'customMethod' does not exist on type 'Action[]'

These are my interfaces:

```
export interface Action {
    Name: string;
    someFunc(): void;
}

export interface ActionCollection {
    Actions: Action[];
}
```

Then in my code I'm trying to use a method that has not been described YET in the interface but it is available at runtime. This method is is available from the Actions array within ActionsCollection, just like a native .length property.

```
let myAC: ActionCollection = new ActionCollection( stuff );
myAC.Actions.customMethod(); // Note that it is attached to Actions
```

My question is how do I define it in the interfaces?

I've tried something like this, but I got errors:

```
export interface Action<> {
    customMethod(): any;
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be able to do `new ActionCollection` as `ActionCollection` is an interface, you don't get an error there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your actions array to have this method then you either need to add it to the `Array` interface:

```
interface Array<T> {
    customMethod(): void;
}
```

And then all arrays will have it:

```
let a = [];
a.customMethod();
```

But that's probably not what you're after, instead just define your own array:

```
export interface Action {
    Name: string;
    someFunc(): void;
}

export interface ActionsArray extends Array<Action> {
    customMethod(): void;
}

export interface ActionCollection {
    Actions: ActionsArray;
}
```

You say that you already implemented the actual function, so this should be enough.